# Web scraping the data.imf.org site by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button

using the selenium python package i am trying to automate the selection and download of data from the following webpage: https://data.imf.org/?sk=9d6028d4-f14a-464c-a2f2-59b2cd424b85&sid=1390030341854. What I am trying to do is to click on the button on the left side (Counterpart Country) and then, once the dialog box open, to select a specific country. Using the code I am enclosing I have succeded in opening the dialog box and in making the input of the country, but then i am not able to click the search button, select the country and apply the canges.

Here it is the code i have used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import os
import glob
import shutil
import time
import chromedriver_binary
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

pagina='https://data.imf.org/?sk=9d6028d4-f14a-464c-a2f2-59b2cd424b85&sid=1390030341854'

path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa,executable_path=path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get(pagina)
time.sleep(10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'RoundButton27215')))
country = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='RoundButton27215']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", country)
textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TextBox42785']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")
textbox.clear()
textbox.send_keys('Italy')
textbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TextBox42785"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", textbutton)
```

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? try using `pip list` to check

Comment: I have selenium 4.1.0